# Shopify order webhooks

Tags: shopify, webhooks

I looked into the different order webhooks and was wondering when they are triggered. This is what I figured out so far:

1. `orders/updated` is fired whenever an order is changed in any way, including when an order is created (even before it was authorized and `orders/create` is fired), closed or cancelled
2. `orders/create` is fired when the user authorizes the payment
3. `orders/paid` is fired when the merchant accepts the payment
4. `orders/fulfilled` is fired when the merchant fulfills the order
5. `orders/cancelled` is fired when the order is cancelled

Since `orders/updated` is also fired whenever the other hooks are fired, it seems as if adding an update webhook would be good enough for keeping a local datastore synced to the shop data. However, I want to confirm that my understanding of those webhooks is correct, i.e. is it true that `orders/updated` is always fired whenever an order changes in any way. and that the other webhooks are just aimed at more specific use cases?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'd say for sake of keeping the code easier to understand it would be in your best interest to handle the appropriate webhooks just to keep the code easier to understand.

If all you're doing is tracking really general stuff, it's probably fine.

Also, on all state changes of an order the `orders/updated` webhook is fired.