# Shopify - difference between orders/create and orders/paid webhooks

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

From [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12738309/shopify-order-webhooks),

orders/create is fired when the user authorizes the payment

orders/paid is fired when the merchant accepts the payment

If the customers use credit cards, what's the difference? If the customers use cash on delivery (COD), will orders/create fire? Which webhook runs earlier than another one?

I'm using orders/paid webhooks but they are not triggered for COD orders

Answer (score 1):

A merchant can create an order without it being paid (created from the Shopify admin). So one can be created but not paid.

This answer explains it https://community.shopify.com/c/shopify-apis-and-sdks/order-created-and-paid/td-p/1309845